# MySQL 5.6 - Complex table update

Tags: mysql

I have two tables as follows:

Enclosure

```
+-------+--------------+-----------+-----------+
| name  | serialnumber | VCenabled | BCenabled |
+-------+--------------+-----------+-----------+
| ENC01 | 12345        |           |           |
| ENC02 | 45678        |           |           |
| ENC03 | 11222        |           |           |
+-------+--------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Interconnect

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| description | baynumber | enclosureserialnumber |
+-------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| VC          | 1         | 12345                 |
| VC          | 2         | 12345                 |
| BC          | 3         | 12345                 |
| VC          | 1         | 45678                 |
| BC          | 3         | 45678                 |
+-------------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

I need to update the `VCenabled` and `BCenabled` columns in the `Enclosure` table. `VCenabled` should contain a count of the corresponding rows in the `Interconnect` table.  Likewise for `BCenabled`.

Here is what I need to end up with:

```
+-------+--------------+-----------+-----------+
| name  | serialnumber | VCenabled | BCenabled |
+-------+--------------+-----------+-----------+
| ENC01 | 12345        | 2         | 1         |
| ENC02 | 45678        | 1         | 1         |
| ENC03 | 11222        |           |           |
+-------+--------------+-----------+-----------+
```

I was able to come up with this SQL query, but I'm not having much luck turning this into an update.  Also, this query works if I run it in Flyspeed Query but if I run it in MySQL Workbench, I get a 1064 error: Error in SQL syntax.

```
Select
  enclosure.name,
  enclosure.vcenabled,
  count(*)
From
  enclosure Inner Join
  interconnect On interconnect.enclosureserialnumber = enclosure.serialnumber
Where
  interconnect.description like '%VC%'
Group By
  enclosure.serialnumber
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could show the query you currently using?

Comment: You should definitely **not** store aggregate data in columns. That is what aggregate functions (like `COUNT`) are for

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
update enclosure t1, 
(select count(*) as x,enclosureserialnumber from interconnect where description='VC') t2,
(select count(*) as y,enclosureserialnumber from interconnect where description='BC') t3
set t1.VCenabled = t2.x,t1.BCenabled=t3.x
where t1.serialnumber=t2.enclosureserialnumber
and t2.serialnumber=t3.enclosureserialnumber
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50690/1)

```
UPDATE 
  Enclosure e
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      enclosureserialnumber,
      SUM(CASE WHEN description = 'VC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS VC,
      SUM(CASE WHEN description = 'BC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BC
    FROM
      Interconnect 
    GROUP BY
      enclosureserialnumber
  ) q1
    ON e.serialnumber = q1.enclosureserialnumber
SET
  VCenabled = q1.VC,
  BCenabled = q1.BC;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work using a subquery with the update:

```
update Enclosure e
join (
  select enclosureserialnumber,
    sum(case when i.description = 'VC' then 1 else 0 end) vcsum,
    sum(case when i.description = 'BC' then 1 else 0 end) bcsum
  from Interconnect i
  group by i.enclosureserialnumber
  ) i
  on e.serialnumber = i.enclosureserialnumber
set e.VCenabled = i.vcsum,
   e.BCenabled = i.bcsum;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e39d9/1)

Comment: Getting error 1064 when run from MySQL Workbench.  No errors when run from Flyspeed, but I got all zeros in the vcenabled and bcenabled columns.

Comment: @user2934368 -- please review the fiddle and update accordingly to show the issues.  Appears to be working for me.  Thanks.

Comment: It works.  I simplified the description field in my post, so I had to change it to LIKE '%VC%' and it worked perfectly.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @user2934368 -- no worries, glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

```
update Enclosure as E1 set E1.VCenabled = (select count(*) from Interconnect as I where I.enclosureserialnumber = E1.serialnumber and I.description = 'VC');
```

similar for BC

Tested... if any error occurs, please check for any spelling typos.

for output to my system....

http://pastebin.com/B0bUDYX6